# Change background color of TAchart series

Tags: delphi, lazarus

i Have this code for drawing a profile of one plane figure.

```
  Chart1.Series.Clear;
  Lser:=TLineSeries.Create(Chart1);
  for x:= 1 to 20 do
  Lser.AddXY(strtofloat(stringgrid1.Cells[1,x]),strtofloat(stringgrid1.Cells[2,x]));
  chart1.AddSeries(Lser);
  lser.LinePen.Width:=2;
  lser.SeriesColor:=clred;
```

Now, how can change the background color of my plane figure?
Thank you very much

if u see the picture, i want draw only the yellow area (i fill it on paint of windows)
[image]

Comment: +1, good question though, but I think (or better to say I'm almost sure) that is impossible to fill the area *inside* of the line series graph in a formal way. That's what the line graphs are not for. You are most probably looking for the `TAreaSeries`.

Comment: But you have already [`the answer`](http://www.lazarus.freepascal.org/index.php/topic,17157.msg94451.html#msg94451), I would suggest (and I did a comment before, independently on that post) the same, to use the `TAreaSeries` instead of `TLineSeries`.

Comment: yes, I know. I generally prefer to hear more opinions on my questions ;)

Comment: i solved it with TAreaSeries. Thanks all and tanks to TLama for him suggest! ;)

Comment: So to keep the StackOverflow convention you (or me) should post the answer and you should [`accept it`](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/179541). It helps the future visitors with the same problem to find the right solution. So please post your own answer with the solution and accept it (I have to go right now and be away for a while). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all, i solved it with TAreaSeries.

Comment: Please post the code you used to solve the problem, then Accept your answer (click the check mark on the left)

Answer (score 0):

```
chart1.Backwall.Transparent := False;
chart1.Backwall.Color := clgreen;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but, i have this error:
unit1.pas(66,17) Error: identifier idents no member "Backwall"